# c libs to have absolute file path which does not have /./ or /../ components

Tags: c, filepath

I would like to remove all "./", or "../" from a input file path string.
I know that "realpath" removes NOT only "./", or "../" BUT also symbolic link.

Is there a library to remove all "./", or "../" from a input file path string and return the path without "./", or "../"?
//DAUM

Comment: I have posted a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34202207/3744681) that I use for this purpose in that thread with example. It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks; it should work.

Comment: Should I use "canonicalize_filename" library which describe is at http://linux.die.net/man/3/canonicalize_filename?

Comment: `canonicalize_filename` should work fine too... ( I haven't used it though..)